# Doesn't work to play sounds using wolfram language for jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have installed the Wolfram Language to JupyterLab on windows 10 by following the instructions provided here. https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter

It seems to work, however when I try to create a sound by e.g typing Play[Sin[440 2 Pi t], {t, 0, 1}], I only get a png file which I obviously can't play. I have also tried EmitSound[Play[Sin[440 2 Pi t], {t, 0, 1}]], which doesn't seem to do anything. The image bellow shows the code I have tested using wolfram language for jupyter. Like I wrote previously, the sound box at [5] is just a png file, I can't interact with it.

[image]

Comment: ```AudioData[Play[Sin[440 2 \[Pi] t], {t, 0, 0.01}]]; ListLinePlot[%]``` Let's first check if there is `AudioData` being generated. Also clicking the graphic is not useful unless you are clicking on the play button.

Comment: Experiment 2) ```EmitSound[t = Play[Sin[440 2 Pi t], {t, 0, 0.1}]]; ListLinePlot@AudioData[t]``` should generate a sine wave output.

Comment: @Syed Like [this](https://i.imgur.com/A4WSTit.png)?  (No sounds were played when I ran them). The play button is part of the png, I can't click it, I assume it's interactable in mathematica but when I try it with wolfram language for jupyter, the whole box is just a png.

Comment: Same output as I have on desktop system. I should have used something other than `t` above, though. I saw the red color in output labeled `[5]` so I was wondering if this was an error and therefore I asked you to verify it. Post your question on the community website if it is not resolved here in a few days. Also verify that your browser is not blocking the sound: chrome://settings/content/sound